# NoClassDefFoundError when running Scala jar file

Tags: java, scala, jar, noclassdeffounderror, remote-actors

I have a small application with RemoteActors, and I want to make a jar file from it. When I try to execute it it gets this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/actors/Combinators
  at pingpong.PingApp$.main(PingApp.scala:5)
  at pingpong.PingApp.main(PingApp.scala)
  at pingpong.ScalaEntryPoint.main(ScalaEntryPoint.java:5)
  ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.actors.Combinators
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
  ... 8 more
```

I have included scala-library.jar in my jar file, and it is in the classpath. Otherwise java would stop at finding the class `ScalaObject`.

Comment: More runtime information would be good. Are you trying to build a jar with Maven? Or just getting it run with Eclipse?

Comment: At a minimum, show the command line that you invoked, and mention what version of Scala you are using.

Comment: the command: java -jar myjar.jar 
I'm using scala 2.7.7 final

Comment: 2.7.7? why? Combinators is in scala-library.jar so its a classpath issue. try putting the library.jar into classpath explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a version mismatch between the Scala plugin on Eclipse and the installed Scala version. actors/Combinators.scala appeared in 2.8, and the Eclipse plugin was 2.8 however I included 2.7.7 scala-library.jar

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't handle "jar within a jar".  The default classloader can't load classes that way.

From your stacktrace, it looks like you've used eclipse's export->java->runnable jar.  It is supposed to include a special classloader which handles jar in jar loading but it seems not to be working.

I would guess that something went wrong building the jar or it is confused by scala being both included in your jar and your classpath.  You could try this again using "extract libraries into jar" rather than "package libraries into jar".  You could try it without scala on the classpath.

Failing that there are other options if you want a single shippable jar:

- You can unpack all of the jars you depend on and repack them with your compiled classes (should be what "extract" does above).  Maven's [shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin) plugin can help with this.
- You can use a different solution that will provide a classloader implementation that can load nested jars, like [OneJar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net)

Hope this is useful, if you need more help you need to describe exactly what steps you take to produce this jar, and probably the output of "jar tvf myjar.jar" will help too.

Comment: I tried to extract the scala library to the jar file but the result is the same exception. It seems there is no scala.actors.Combinators class in scala-library.jar

Comment: Can you run "jar tvf myjar.jar" and make sure that scala-lang is shown as being in there?  If that is the case, extract (jar xvf) myjar.jar into a temporary folder and then inspect the scala-lang.jar that is present the same way?

Comment: jar tvf ping.jar | grep scala-lang  shows no results. I extracted the jar and didn't find any file named scala-lang.

Comment: This means it isn't being included by whatever steps you are taking to try and include it hence the ClassNotFoundException.  Likely this is a question best raised with eclipse.org.  In the meantime I would suggest you use maven's shade plugin, OneJar, or just include it on your runtime classpath.